# How do you cast COM pointers in C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, casting, com

When using COM objects it is unsafe to do a standard cast. Instead, you should use the `as` member function.

In C++:

```cpp
//cast COMPtr1 to type COMPtrType2:
COMPtrType2 COMPtr2;
ComPtr1.as(COMPtr2);
```

How do I do this in C?

Comment: C++ really is much more suitable for COM programming than C

Comment: @GovindParmar lol I know

Comment: You call `IUnknown::QueryInterface`. Those C++ wrappers do that behind the scenes; in C, you get to do everything manually.

Comment: Badasahog, There are various C compilers in "Windows"  Which one are you using?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik please post this as an answer